# ssl_error_bad_mac_alert error in Firefox

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate, https, openssl

I've installed an SSL cert onto an Apache2 server which serves intranet content.  Internet Explorer 6/7 and Safari 4 can connect to the site just fine.  However, when I attempt to access the site with Firefox, I get the following error:

```
An error occurred during a connection to intranet:8080.

SSL peer reports incorrect Message Authentication Code.

(Error code: ssl_error_bad_mac_alert)
```

I'm running a standard Apache2/OpenSSL setup on Solaris 10.  I tried enabling the SSLSessionCache, but that did not fix the problem.

We're using an internal CA, which is trusted by IE.

I can also reproduce the problem with curl:

```
* About to connect() to intranet port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying x.x.x.x... connected
* Connected to intranet (x.x.x.x) port 8080 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/share/curl/curl-ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSLv2, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Server hello (2):
* error:140943FC:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad record mac
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) error:140943FC:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert bad record mac
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem was caused by Apache2 being compiled with the **worker mpm**.

There used to be further information at http://opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=265271 but this now returns an error page.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem but with a site that stopped working after a Firefox upgrade.  
**The Fix**:
Change Firefox security settings.  It seems Firefox is disabling older ssl standards.
In Firefox address bar enter `about:config`
In search enter `security.ssl3`
Toggle false values to `true`
You should now be able to get to your sites.

Comment: Not really "the fix", but sometimes, when you're administering some old machines that are not publicly exposed, you need to do that...